# How to get rows count in sql result with group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, phpmyadmin

I would like to know how is possible to get **rows count** in result of sql statement with **group by**. As I know count aggregation counts the result of grouped rows but I would like to know the count of all rows in result but **without subselect**. Does anybody know how PhpMyAdmin count rows returned by query with grouped rows? I think there is a special command for mysql but dont remember the name.

Comment: Are you thinking of [GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)?

Comment: Are you just wanting to count the results returned? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607264/how-can-i-count-the-numbers-of-rows-that-a-mysql-query-returned

Comment: You can use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52532959/2469308

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It looks like the answer I was looking for. Thaks.

Comment: If there are another solutions please write it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count the numbers of rows that a mysql query returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607264/how-can-i-count-the-numbers-of-rows-that-a-mysql-query-returned)